# Changing devise default layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise

I'm trying to get devise to display a different layout template from the defaults for certain aspects.

I have this working when the user goes to the login page, but I need to display a different layout for sign up, forgotten password, and reset.

This is the current code in my application controller:

```
layout :layout

  private
  def layout
    # only turn it off for login pages:
    is_a?(Devise::SessionsController) ? "login" : "application"
    # or turn layout off for every devise controller:
    #devise_controller? && "application"
  end
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you name your alternate layout devise.html.erb, then the gem's controllers will naturally use it, without needing to be asked. Saves some code.

Comment: Here's the documentation showing all possible ways to achieve this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

Comment: For anyone who is interested, this works because of Rails magic, that Rails tries to find layout with same name as the controller to use it. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html#module-ActionView::Layouts-label-Layout+assignment

Comment: I really, really wish I had thought of this before...

Answer (score 47):

Add this lines of code to your application.rb:

```
config.to_prepare do
    Devise::SessionsController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::RegistrationsController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::UnlocksController.layout "your_layout_name"
    Devise::PasswordsController.layout "your_layout_name"
end
```

If you want the same layout for all Devise views, except for when the user is editing its data, you could have something like this:

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.layout "your_layout_name"
  Devise::RegistrationsController.layout proc{ |controller| user_signed_in? ? "application" : "your_layout_name" }
  Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout "your_layout_name"
  Devise::UnlocksController.layout "your_layout_name"            
  Devise::PasswordsController.layout "your_layout_name"        
end
```

For more information you can read this [article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts)

Comment: only problem with the above code is that the registrationscontroller will also effect when a valid logged in user is edit there password

Comment: The easiest way to do are Define in ApplicationController: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts#wiki-define-in-applicationcontroller

Comment: Guys, I did this inside application.rb, but it keeps rendering devise partials without layout I set (I set application.haml the default that I use in the rest of the app: views/layouts/application.haml)  Devise::SessionsController.layout "application"

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to handle the layouts by your self, just do:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Then, look at devise folder at views folder, you will see all the forms you need to customize

Comment: done that, but it still uses my application template, there is bits of information i do not want to display until a user is logged in. its not views as such, its the layouts those views are rendered within

Comment: as for me, I didn't have to touch the layouts, all I did is rails generate devise:views, then, I customized the generated views easily, which are rendered in the default yield

Comment: This doesnt work because it only generates the view.